# How to add text div on top of another div while keeping the ability to hover over the div below it?

Tags: html, css, web

The following code is a simplified version of the problem im facing, know that the text has to be a separate div which will be placed on top using positioning, in short the text needs to be visible to user but should not affect anything on the website.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#box {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#box:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

#text {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="box"></div>

  <div id="text">i still want the color of the box to change even when im hovering over this text</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `pointer-events: none` to the text div.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#box {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#box:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

#text {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="box"></div>

  <div id="text">i still want the color of the box to change even when im hovering over this text</div>

</body>
```

Comment: This works fine when hover property for both elements comes from CSS, but when I'm animating on hover using JQuery I run into a similar problem i.e. the text blocks the hover even with pointer-events set to none.

Comment: can you add a code snippet of the problem you are stating?

Comment: Turns out it was another div way down that was blocking the hover, setting its pointer events to none fixed the problem, not sure why its effects were coming way up but I will surely figure that out. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know that. Happy coding :)

Answer (score -1):

This can not be possible with CSS alone, there is no way to select a parent element in css from child and update the style.

So, You can write a but of JS to do that. Here is the updated code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#box {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#box:hover {
  background-color: blue;
} 
.blue{
  background-color: blue !important;
}

#text {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="box"></div>

  <div id="text" onmouseout="update(false)" onmouseover="update(true)">i still want the color of the box to change even when im hovering over this text</div>
<script>
   function update(updateColor){
        let box = document.getElementById('box');
       if(updateColor){
          box.classList.add("blue");
       }else{
          box.classList.remove("blue");
       }        }
</script>
</body>
```